# Vue, Express app not forwarding requests to index.html on history mode during Heroku deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, heroku

**TL;DR:** Clicking on this https://linkify.herokuapp.com/login gives `not found error` even though I can go to https://linkify.herokuapp.com and see the browser shows https://linkify.herokuapp.com/login after I click login in the navbar.

---

I am trying to deploy a simple app to https://linkify.herokuapp.com and are currently facing issues on history API and server routing.

If you go to this link and linkify.herokuapp.com and click on different links on the navbar you will see that the url in the browser changes. For example, if you click on login, you will see that the url in the browser will change to https://linkify.herokuapp.com/login.

Now if you send a request to the server to get the login page by clicking here https://linkify.herokuapp.com/login you will get not found error.

I assume this is because vue routes are not actual urls and giving not found error when hit enter. I have a /login route. When I go to this view, I can see on Chrome that the link url is https://linkify.herokuapp.com/login. If I hit enter, I get 404 request not found. 
I tried the following piece of code to have all the requests to get the index.html page but I still get `not found` error.

```js
// Serve static assets (build folder) if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
   // Set static folder
   app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"..","client","build")));
   app.get("*", (req, res) => {
       res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,"..", "client", "build", "index.html"));
   });
 }
}
```

I don't think this is a problem due to Heroku but I am including its logs just in case.
Any help is appreciated.

Below is my router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';
import Login from '../views/Login.vue';
import Register from '../views/Register.vue';
import store from '../store/index';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      title: 'Home - Linkify',
      metaTags: [
        {
          name: 'description',
          content: 'The home page of Linkify'
        },
        {
          property: 'og:description',
          content: 'The home page of Linkify'
        }
      ]
    },
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      store.dispatch('fetchAccessToken');
      if (store.state.accessToken) {
        next('/manage');
      }
      else {
        next();
      }
    },
  meta: {
    title: 'Login - Linkify',
    metaTags: [
      {
        name: 'description',
        content: 'The login page of Linkify'
      },
      {
        property: 'og:description',
        content: 'The login page of Linkify'
      }
    ]
  },
},
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'Register',
    component: Register,
    meta: {
      title: 'Register - Linkify',
      metaTags: [
        {
          name: 'description',
          content: 'The register page of Linkify'
        },
        {
          property: 'og:description',
          content: 'The register page of Linkify'
        }
      ]
    }   
  }, {
    path: '*',
    name: '404', /*Serve this route for pages not found*/
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "pagenoutfound" */ '../views/PageNotFound.vue'),
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
});

});


export default router;
```

below is from my App.vue where i mount the app

```
...
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: createEle => createEle(App)
}).$mount('#app-container');
...
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="description" content="URL Shortener ">
  <meta name="keywords" content="URL,Shortener,Analytics,Fraud, Detection">
  <meta name="author" content="Yigit Alparslan">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/img/icons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/img/icons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/img/icons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/img/icons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/img/icons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/img/icons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/img/icons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/img/icons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href=".img/icons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/img/icons/android-icon-192x192.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/img/icons/favicon-96x96.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/img/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/img/icons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

  <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
    <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled.
      Please enable it to continue.</strong>
  </noscript>
  <div id="app-container"></div>
  <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>

</html>
```

server.js

```
// Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const path = require('path')
const passport = require("passport");
var device = require('express-device');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const flash = require("express-flash");
const layout = require("express-layout");
const { check } = require("express-validator");
const helmet = require('helmet');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback'); // Adding history redirects the /ggl7283 to /index.html

// Endpoints import
const home = require('./endpoints/home');
const shorten = require('./endpoints/shorten');
const geturls = require('./endpoints/geturls');
const redirect = require('./endpoints/redirect');
const login = require('./endpoints/login');
const register = require('./endpoints/register');
const savecustomurl = require('./endpoints/savecustomurl');
const generateqrcode = require('./endpoints/generateqrcode');
const { postcontact } = require('./endpoints/contact');

// Server setup
const app = express();

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Passport config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// Define all middlewares
const middlewares = [
  helmet(),
  layout(),
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "client", "public")),
  bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }),
  bodyParser.json(),
  flash(),
  cors(),
  device.capture(),
  morgan('tiny'),
  history()

];
app.use(middlewares);

// Capture device info: This will include a .device 
// field to each request object
device.enableDeviceHelpers(app)

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Database setup
const { MONGODB } = require('./config/keys.js');
mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => {

    console.log('MongoDB Connected');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('MongoDB failed to connect')
  })

// Endpoints setup
app.get('/', home);
app.get('/:shorturl', redirect);
app.post('/api/login', login);
app.post('/api/register', register);

// Serve static assets (build folder) if in production  
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'dist')));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "..","client", "dist", "index.html"));
  });
}

// Server run
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Root level package.json

```
{
  "name": "linkify.herokuapp.com",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install --prefix server && npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
    "start": "npm start --prefix server",
    "client": "npm run serve --prefix client",
    "server":"npm run server --prefix server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ya332/url-shortener.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ya332/url-shortener/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ya332/url-shortener#readme"
}
```

App structure

```
>package.json
>server
   >server.js
>client
   >dist
       >img/icons (all the icons)
   >public
   >index.html
   >manifest.json
   >favicon.ico
   >src>components
```

heroku logs --tail

```
2020-04-12T04:45:13.187836+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-04-12T04:45:13.190934+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-04-12T04:45:37.259512+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-12T04:45:37.259579+00:00 app[web.1]: > linkify.herokuapp.com@1.0.0 start /app
2020-04-12T04:45:37.259585+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm start --prefix server
2020-04-12T04:45:37.259585+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-12T04:45:37.573868+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-12T04:45:37.573915+00:00 app[web.1]: > linkify@1.0.0 start /app/server
2020-04-12T04:45:37.573916+00:00 app[web.1]: > node -r dotenv/config server.js
2020-04-12T04:45:37.573916+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-12T04:45:38.656416+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2020-04-12T04:45:38.656431+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production
environment, as it will leak
2020-04-12T04:45:38.656432+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2020-04-12T04:45:38.668645+00:00 app[web.1]: Server listening on port 18065
2020-04-12T04:45:38.796155+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB Connected
2020-04-12T04:45:38.932110+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-04-12T04:45:43.164498+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=linkify.herokuapp.com request_id=345bf302-9037-40c8-8fdd-d284ca7207b1 fwd="72.94.180.182" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=86ms status=304 bytes=430 protocol=https
2020-04-12T04:45:43.618951+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=linkify.herokuapp.com request_id=9e10b1ea-7233-4cbe-8974-131430f1a8a5 fwd="72.94.180.182" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=430 protocol=https
2020-04-12T04:45:43.641271+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=linkify.herokuapp.com request_id=78023e22-64eb-4685-8085-bf8de5bb2145 fwd="72.94.180.182" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28ms status=200 bytes=1620 protocol=https
2020-04-12T04:45:43.719714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/img/icons/favicon-32x32.png" host=linkify.herokuapp.com request_id=f1a3daa0-6ee0-474e-9672-e38698134d5e fwd="72.94.180.182" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=430 protocol=https
2020-04-12T04:45:43.691637+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/img/icons/android-icon-144x144.png" host=linkify.herokuapp.com request_id=39ca47e4-9653-4858-aed0-5d40deb3fd6d fwd="72.94.180.182" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21ms status=304 bytes=431 protocol=https
```